How to check if a chrome tab is an installed Desktop App/Shortcut?
I'm building a browser extension, and I want to distinguish between users' regular tabs and installed apps/shortcuts. How do I check the difference?
I looked at the chrome.tabs API and found nothing to help me. If I go to the browser's task manager I see that it shows the difference. Regular tab processes have the "Tab" name while installed shortcuts have the "App" name.

Use chrome.windows API e.g. chrome.windows.getCurrent() and check if type is app.
